# Quartz in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, quartz-graphics

i would like to implement a quartz composition into my iOS app in xcode 4. Despite searching everywhere for an explanation on how to do this, i have come up empty. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Quartz Composer for iPhone, therefore, no Quartz Compositions.

Unless your willing to do it through Safari, (i.e. a `UIWebView`)

See:

http://stakeventures.com/articles/2007/06/28/games-on-iphone-via-quartz-composer

Comment: what is apple talking about then here:
http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/graphics-and-animation.html
under quartz 2d

Comment: @Barry: Quartz 2D is a drawing API. Quartz Composer is an application that uses various drawing APIs to make cool effects and stuff.